# Does set affinity ensure that only one core resources are used?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, affinity

I just wanted to find out if setting cpu affinity ensure that the application runs only on that core ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what affinity masks are for. However you need this very rarely. The only reasonable use case I can imagine is restricting the number of cores depending on the end-user license agreement.

Comment: Also windows scheduler will try to resume thread to run on the same core (on which it was run before) if possible.